# Problemas com paginação no WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, paginação

Estou com um problema para fazer aparecer a paginação numa página de WordPress usando WP-Pagenavi.

O `post_type` "pronamic_event" existe no banco e trás todos os itens da consulta.

Consegui identificar que o erro está no retorno da variável `$paged` que não retorna nada, assim, ele sempre pega o else da condição ternária, que nesse caso é 1. Como descobrir onde está o `$paged`?

Segue o código.

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>
<div class="agenda-10-wrap">
<div class="top">
    <h3><?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))  bcn_display() ?></h3>
    <h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="col-01">
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => '12',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'post_type' => 'pronamic_event'
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                //loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>
                <li>
                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails');
                    } 
                    ?>
                    <p><?php pronamic_the_start_date('d.m.y');?> - <?php pronamic_the_location();?></p>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();?>
                    <p><?php echo string_limit_words($excerpt,25); ?>...</p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Leia mais</a>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-pager">
            <nav>
                <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){
                    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) );
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                } ?>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-02">
        <?php get_sidebar( 'publicidade-ultimas' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consegui identificar que o erro está no retorno da variável $paged que não retorna nada, assim, ele sempre pega o else da condição ternária, que nesse caso é 1. Como descobrir onde está o $paged???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a página que você está usando esse código é usada como [**static front page**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) você tem que verificar o parâmetro [**page**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#static_front_page) também.

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => '12',
   'paged'          => $paged,
   'post_type'      => 'pronamic_event'
);
```

Comment: Existe alguma forma deu encontrar essa variável paged ou page??? O problema é ele, ele não retorna nada.

Comment: Sim, da maneira que eu coloquei no código. Verifica o paged primeiro, depois o page. Deu certo ?

Comment: Então, não deu certo com nenhum dos dois, mas fiz a query diretamente usando o WP_Query e depois programei o paginador na mão, estava muito atrasado com o job. muito obrigado pela força!!!